# Electron, RxJS —Observable IPC channels & context isolation

Tags: rxjs, electron, observable, ipc

Here's a minimal reproducible example that shows that RxJS observables work fine with context isolation **off**:

main process:

```js
app.whenReady().then(async () => {
  const bwin = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: false,
      preload: path.resolve(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  });

  await bwin.loadFile('renderer.html');
  bwin.show();

  let count = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
    bwin.webContents.send('count', count++);
  }, 200);
});
```

preload script

```js
window.MY_NAMESPACE = {
  count$: fromEvent(ipcRenderer, 'count')
};
```

renderer process

```html
<body>
  <div id="response"></div>
  <script>
    window.MY_NAMESPACE.count$.subscribe(([ev, count]) => {
      document.querySelector('#response').innerHTML += `${count}<br>`;
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

[image]

Now I turn **on** the context isolation and use the Context Bridge API in my preload script:

main process:

```
webPreferences: {
  …
  contextIsolation: true,
  …
}
```

preload script:

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('MY_NAMESPACE', {
  count$: fromEvent(ipcRenderer, 'count')
});
```

Then in my renderer process I see this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: window.MY_NAMESPACE.count$.subscribe is not a function

Why?

I am aware that Electron has some restrictions when passing data through IPC channels but I don't think that's the reason for the issue I have.

Additional resources:

- https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/28176

Answer (score 3):

As you are aware, with [Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation) enabled, Electron runs your `preload.js` script  and render process(es) in separate context.

> "This means that the window object that your preload script has access to is actually a different object than the website would have access to. For example, if you set window.hello = 'wave' in your preload script and context isolation is enabled, window.hello will be undefined if the website tries to access it."

This is what is happening in your instance. When context isolation is enabled, the transport mechanism only allows specific objects types through such as booleans, strings, arrays, plain objects, etc. Anything that can't be serialised using the [Structured Clone Algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) (such as functions) can't be communicated between the main process and render process(es). See [Object serialization](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#object-serialization) for more information.

As you can see in your error message, `.subscribe` is the function within `window.MY_NAMESPACE.count$.subscribe`.

Therefore, the RxJS [fromEvent](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent) will not work when `contextIsolation` is set to `true`.

Instead, this functionality will need to be done the old fashion way.

---

Note, in my `preload.js` script, I do not implement concrete functions. Instead, I only use this script to identify whitelisted channels names. It separates concerns and keeps things simple.

`preload.js` (main thread)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [
            'app:count' // Channel name
        ],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

`main.js` (main thread)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

const nodePath = require("path");

let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); })
        .then(() => { count(); })

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

function count() {
    let count = 0;

    setInterval(() => {
        window.webContents.send('app:count', count++);
    }, 200);
}
```

---

`index.html` (render thread)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="response"></div>
    </body>

    <script>
        let response = document.getElementById('response');

        window.ipcRender.receive('app:count', (count) => {
            response.innerText = count;
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: @customcommander Edited the opening sentence to clarify separation is between the `preload.js` script and the render process(es). Thanks for the pick-up.

Answer (score -1):

Feel free to copy the code from https://github.com/linonetwo/electron-ipc-cat , the concept is just use IPC message to connect client and server.